# Dynamic archive of posts by date

Tags: posts, query-posts, list

I'm currently working on an intranet site for a big company and based on the project description, there will be a lot of articles posted everyday so this website will need various archive pages with different queries for users to quickly find articles based on their chosen criteria. I sorted out all of them (thanks to StackExchange!!) but I can't figure out how to create something like below:

[image]

I want a set number of lines (10 on each sides) each containing the date where posts were published ordered by date. I know how to query posts by date, but to use that it will mean that I will need to update this list everyday manually which is impractical.

Is there a way to dynamically create this list (relative to "today's" date)?

Thank you in advance for your time on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I have now resolved this issue. For whomever is interested, please find my code below (I've included everything to a shortcode to facilitate adding it anywhere I want):

```
function archiveday() {
$x=1;
    do {

$result = date('l jS F Y',strtotime("-$x days")); 
$year= date('Y',strtotime("-$x days"));
$month= date('n',strtotime("-$x days"));
$day= date('j',strtotime("-$x days"));
$my_query2 = get_posts("post_status=publish&post_type=post&year=$year&monthnum=$month&day=$day");

        if ($my_query2){
            echo '<a href="http://EXAMPLE.COM/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/">'.$result.'</a> ('. count($my_query2).') <br>'; }
        else {
            echo $result .' ('. count($my_query2).') <br>';}
    $x++;}
    while ($x<=10);

        wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('archive', 'archiveday');
```

This now outputs the below:

[image]